# Unable to upload custom Plugin

Tags: plugins, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I created a custom plugin to be uploaded on Google Cloud Data Fusion platform, which is based on CDAP platform.
I followed the instructions for developing and deploying plugins but the upload fails when I try to associate the corresponding Json configuration file (generated by IntelliJ itself through the CDAP Maven artifacts) with following error:

```
Artifact artifact:default.record-gen-source.1.0 extends artifacts 'system:cdap-data-streams[4.0.0,5.0.0)/system:cdap-data-pipeline[4.0.0,5.0.0)' that do not exist
```

If I remove the reference to parent artifacts the custom plugin is loaded but it doesn't appear neither as a batch plugin or as a stream plugin (I can understand this, I'm removing the parents references).
What could be the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the plugin you are trying to upload inherits from incorrect parent artifact versions(which in this case `cdap-data-streams` & `cdap-data-pipeline`). The version of these artifacts are based on the version that is available in your current Data Fusion instance (which I believe is 6.1). If the version of cdap-data-pipeline/cdap-data-streams artifact doesn't fall under the range specified then you will be seeing this error. If you edit the version range to be `[4.0.0,7.0.0)` it should work I believe.

Can you try updating the pom.xml if you are using `cdap-maven-plugin` plugin with updated version range [Like here](https://github.com/data-integrations/google-cloud/blob/release/0.13/pom.xml#L612-L615) and rebuild & deploy?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try tomorrow. I had the suspect and gave range from  4.0.0 to 6.0.0 with no success, unfortunately on Maven the pom version is 5.1.2 if I remember correctly. I'll update you ASAP.